# Need a recipes table and categories table in such a way that a recipe can have more then one category

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a website which stores data in mysql. 
Now the situation is that I want a structure in which there should be a table with catogories (cat_id, cat_name) and a recipe table (r_id,r_name and so on). But the condition is that is that a single recipe can have more than one category.And I have to show that all recipes that comes under one categories through php.

All I need is a proper structure.

I am new to DBMS. A help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a junction table to your database schema, something like this:

```
category_recipe (cat_id, r_id)
```

The purpose of this table is to allow a given category to map to more then one recipe.  If you also want to enforce that each recipe may only appear once, then you may add a unique index on the `r_id` column in `category_recipe`.

To find all the recipes that fall under a certain category, you may use the following query:

```
SELECT
    r.r_id, r.r_name
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN category_recipe cr
    ON c.cat_id = cr.cat_id
INNER JOIN recipe r
    ON cr.r_id = r.r_id
WHERE
    c.cat_name = 'some category';
```